# Firefox on the server, can that give trouble?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, audio

I'm working on a project in which we need to download all sorts of files from websites. To reliably do this we also had to be able to do this for links containing javascript. I finally managed to do this by installing firefox on the (Ubuntu 14.04) server and using xvfb and [PyVirtualDisplay](https://github.com/ponty/PyVirtualDisplay) to emulate a display. It works, but I'm not really a good sysadmin, so I can't really oversee the side effects; installing Firefox on a server simply feels wrong.

So my question is; with the firefox installation, the following dependencies were also installed:

> firefox libasound2 libasound2-data libcanberra0 libdbusmenu-glib4
>   libdbusmenu-gtk4 libogg0 libstartup-notification0 libvorbis0a
>   libvorbisfile3 libxcb-util0 sound-theme-freedesktop xul-ext-ubufox

can this become troublesome on a server for some reason? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Tip: you may find [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) useful.

Comment: @cYrus - I first tried with Phantomjs, but unfortunately Phantom doesn't support file downloads..

Comment: What type of server are we even talking about? A dedicated server that’s directly connected to the internet? A server somewhere in a lab? Something else? Because a server is just a regular PC. It won’t explode because you install GUI software.

Comment: can't you use curl or wget ?

Comment: @kramer65 [it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25721515/477168) [seems](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#download) that is possible with [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/).

Comment: @pat - `wget`ting a link such as `javascript:__doPostBack('downloadTicket','')` doesn't really work well.. :-)

Comment: Okay, i read too fast and thought you only talked of downloading files, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox always has vulnerabilities, possibly due to its open source structure. It is okay for everyday users, but highly risky for a server if you attempt to access third-party content outside the server's internal network. This can make it easy for hackers to compromise the server via Firefox Vulnerabilities. I recommend you install a server plugin to download files and run javascript. What software does your server run? If it is Node.JS, I would install a sandbox plugin. If you run apache, you could look at [cordova.js.](https://github.com/apache/cordova-js)

Comment: Note, it is the user that makes installing browsers on servers "risky". Browsers do not introduce additional attackable surface area, so there is no risk to installing a browser per se. using it in an unsafe manner however is a differant story. Using the browser to design/debug/test locally hosted content is harmless.

Comment: Good points. We're using the server to both serve the website, an api for the app, and also scrape people's emails, click on links, and download stuff (PDFs) from the website in those links. So you're right in saying that this is potentially a very big security risk. I'm running Nginx as a webserver. I've been wanting to use docker to containerize things, I guess running the firefox scraping from a separate docker container would already be better. Do you think that would be a good idea to make things a bit safer?

Comment: Yes, that would definitely be more secure. It would be a big improvement. Good idea!